# Fedora 25 Workstation Image for VirtualBox

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

For some odd reason, everytime I install Fedora 24's ISO on Virtual Box, after the installation is complete, and I reboot the image, it always goes back to the installation screen (instead of a login screen).

When I tried to install Fedora 25 on Virtual Box, there was some incompatible error message.

Am using Windows 7 as my host...

Is there a safe place on the Internet where one can download preconfigured Fedora VM Images (VDI) for Virtual Box?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Some installers don't eject the CDROM - you can do this yourself in the *Settings* dialog.

Comment: I have the same issue, these are the steps to reproduce (basically followed this post: https://fedoramagazine.org/install-fedora-virtualbox-guest/):

* Install Fedora (KDE) using ISO on VirtualBox (Latest version)
* Boot into VM (Works fine)
* `sudo dnf -y update`
* `sudo dnf -y install gcc automake make kernel-headers kernel-devel perl`
* `sudo /run/media/user/VBOXADDITIONS*/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
* Reboot VM

After that I have the choice of Linux 4.8 or 4.9 (Default) - I select 4.9 from GRUB.
I then see the Fedora logo, then black screen and that VirtualBox window is locked up.